# How can I parse out text from a string that uses pipes to separate elements of a vector in R?

Tags: r

For `R`, I have a string that contains information about 3 grades. They look like

```
"First Grade|Third Grade|Second Grade|Third Grade|First Grade"
```

I would like to convert this into a vector, which I am hoping to equivalent to the output of:

```
c("First Grade","Third Grade","Second Grade","Third Grade","First Grade")
> [1] "First Grade"  "Third Grade"  "Second Grade" "Third Grade"  "First Grade"
```

Is there a way to do this in R? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `unlist(strsplit(string_to_split, "\\|"))`?

Comment: Can you explain why you write "They"? Do you have perhaps more than one string? In what data structure are those? Are they possibly imported from file? Maybe even tabular data? There might be a better aproach than using `strsplit`. Or maybe not.

Comment: `scan(text = string, what = '', sep = '|')`

Answer (score 3):

With `stringr`, you can use `str_split`. With `simplify = TRUE`, the output would be a matrix, and we can use `c()` to combine them into a vector. Note that we'll need to escape the `|` sign with double slashes `\\`.

```
library(stringr)

string <- "First Grade|Third Grade|Second Grade|Third Grade|First Grade"
c(str_split(string, "\\|", simplify = T))

[1] "First Grade"  "Third Grade"  "Second Grade" "Third Grade" 
[5] "First Grade"
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) scan** Assuming the input is `x` shown in the Note at the end, we can use `scan`.  The text= argument is the input, the what= argument tells it to regard the fields as character, the sep= argument gives the separator character and the quiet= argument tells it not to display additional information.  No packages are used.

```
scan(text = x, what = "", sep = "|", quiet = TRUE)
## [1] "First Grade"  "Third Grade"  "Second Grade" "Third Grade"  "First Grade"
```

**2) strsplit/unlist** Another possibility is `strsplit` followed by `unlist`.  The fixed=TRUE argument tells it to regard | as an ordinary character, otherwise it has special meaning which we do not want here.  `strsplit` produces a one element list containing the required vector so we unlist it to just get the vector.  Again, no packages are used.

```
unlist(strsplit(x, "|", fixed = TRUE))
## [1] "First Grade"  "Third Grade"  "Second Grade" "Third Grade"  "First Grade"
```

This could also be expressed as a pipeline:

```
x |> strsplit("|", fixed = TRUE) |> unlist()
## [1] "First Grade"  "Third Grade"  "Second Grade" "Third Grade"  "First Grade"
```

If the input were actually a vector of character strings such as `c(x, x)` then we could omit the unlist part and we would get a list of character strings as output.

### Note

```
x <- "First Grade|Third Grade|Second Grade|Third Grade|First Grade"
```